# Calculate time difference between two times represented as longs

Tags: java, time

I am trying to calculate the difference between two times, which are represented as longs in the Format HHmm 24 hour time. E.g 4:30pm is represented by the long 0430.

I am happy for the difference to be in minutes.

Is there a simple calculation that can be done to achieve this? I am aware of Java's Date class, however I want to avoid having to store dummy date information just for a calculation on time.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a really awful way to represent times, not least because if you write `0430` in code, that's interpreted in octal.

Comment: Are you sure 4:30pm is represented as `0430` and not `1630`?

Comment: And if you do store it numerically in the specified format - you do not need more than 1 byte.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you thought about it? How would you do it "by hand"?

Comment: I would suggest using `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Java's LocalTime class does not require you to use a dummy date if you want to just represent time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that this is a really, really bad way to store times, the easiest way to do this is to convert the HHMM time to minutes since the start of the day:

```
long strangeTimeFormatToMinutes(long time) {
  long minutes = time % 100;
  long hours   = time / 100;
  return minutes + 60 * hours;
}
```

Then just use plain old subtraction to get the difference.

You may also want to add validation that `minutes` and `hours` are in the ranges you expect, i.e. 0-59 and 0-23.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you didn't want to use the Date class because it required you to use a dummy date.  The LocalTime class does not require that.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(6,15,30,200); // h, m, s, nanosecs
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(6,30,30,320);
Duration d = Duration.between(start, end);
System.out.println(d.getSeconds()/60);
```

Comment: This is true, but OP would still need to know how to extract the hour and minute from the long to pass to the ctor - and if you've got those, why not just subtract them?

Comment: I didn't mean to answer his exact question, which dealt with representing dates as long values.  I interpreted his question to say that he chose this representation only because Java did not provide a time representation without a date.  Of course, he may not want to change his representation, perhaps because he already has code written that depends on it.  But I hoped to provide an answer to the more general question of calculating differences between times without including dummy dates.

Answer (score 0):

## Pad zeros

First convert your integer to a 4-character string, padding with leading zeros.

For example, `430` becomes `0430` and parsed as `04:30`. Or, `15` becomes `0015` and parsed as quarter past midnight, `00:15`.

```
String input = String.format( "%04d", yourTimeAsInteger );
```

## `LocalDate`

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day value with no date and no time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HHmm" );

LocalTime ld = LocalTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```